# Find Monotone Increasing or Decreasing based on first value of sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

let $s_1=k$ and $s_{n+1}=\sqrt{4s_{n}-1}$.

For what values of k is the sequence monotone increasing and monotone decreasing.

my expectation is that its increasing from [1.5) and decreasing from [5,inf) but I dont know how to show it

Comment: I edited this. Was I correct?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following. For every n $\in \mathbb{N_{\geq{1}}}$ we have the following:
$$
4s_n - 1 \geq 0 \iff s_n \geq \frac{1}{4}.
$$
In particular $k \geq 1/4$
$$
s_{n+1} \geq s_n \iff \sqrt{4s_n - 1} \geq s_n \iff 4s_n - 1 \geq s_n \iff s_n \leq 2 + \sqrt{3}
$$
Now, given that $s_n \geq 2 + \sqrt{3}$ what happens to $s_{n+1}$? Answering this question should give you the answer to your question. Hope this helps.